# Parentheses disappear after formatting in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, eslint, prettier

I write in vscode this statement in js:

```
   el.style.width = (this.elementWidth + round * 10) + "px";
```

After autosave / formatting (prettier) it turns to this:

```
   el.style.width = this.elementWidth + round * 10 + "px";
```

How do I change the settings to leave the parentheses without turning off prettier formatting?

Comment: In this particular case, are you sure the altered code does not work properly? I strongly disagree with what that tool is doing, but here I think that the first `+` should still be a numeric addition.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the behaviour you are describing is an [old, long-discussed issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/187) that they, `prettier`, are not willing to fix